# How can stored procedure return no rows when called from BIDS but return rows when called from SSMS when using the same parameter?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssrs-2008

Using SSRS 2008R2 with a SQL Server 2005 database for the Data Source.

I have a report (.rdl file) built in Business Intelligence Development Studio (VS 2008). It uses a stored procedure as the source of the data. The proc takes one parameter, an INT which is a unique key for the main table in the one SELECT in the proc.

For some parameter values, executing the proc from within the Query Designer of BIDS returns no rows. Executing the **same procedure** from SSMS using the **same parameter value** does return rows. Profiler shows the same SELECT regardless of whether the call is made from BIDS or SSMS. How could they get different results?

Here is the proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Report_BatchEdit]
    @BatchAltId INT
AS
   SELECT   b.[BatchAltId]
            , fs.[Name] AS [FundingSource]
            , b.[StartDate] AS [StartDate]
            , b.[StopDate] AS [StopDate]
            , b.[Description]
            , b.[Created]
            , bl.[BillId]
            , COALESCE(c.[Name], bill.RecipientCustomerName) AS [CustomerName]
            , COALESCE(ri.[Identifier], bill.[RecipientIdentifier]) AS [MedicaidNumber]
            , bill.[NetTotal] AS [ClaimAmount]
            , bl.[BillingCodeCode] AS [BillingCode]
            , bl.[BillingCodeDescription] AS [BillingCodeDescription]
            , bl.[StartDate] AS [FromDate]
            , bl.[StopDate] AS [ToDate]
            , bl.[UnitSizeName] AS [UnitSize]
            , bl.[CalculatedUnits] AS [Units]
            , bl.[Rate]
            , bl.[Amount]
            , fs.UsesModifiers
            , CASE WHEN fs.UsesModifiers = 1 THEN rm1.[Code] ELSE NULL END AS [RateModifier1Code]
            , CASE WHEN fs.UsesModifiers = 1 THEN rm2.[Code] ELSE NULL END AS [RateModifier2Code]
            , CASE WHEN fs.UsesModifiers = 1 THEN rm3.[Code] ELSE NULL END AS [RateModifier3Code]
            , CASE WHEN fs.UsesModifiers = 1 THEN rm4.[Code] ELSE NULL END AS [RateModifier4Code]
    FROM    [Batch] AS b 
            JOIN [Bill] AS bill ON b.[BatchId] = bill.[BatchId] 
            JOIN [BillLine] AS bl ON bill.[BillId] = bl.[BillId]
            JOIN [Customer] AS fs ON b.[PayerCustomerId] = fs.[CustomerId]
            LEFT JOIN [Customer] AS c ON bill.[RecipientCustomerId] = c.[CustomerId]
            LEFT JOIN [RecipientIdentifier] AS ri ON b.[PayerCustomerId] = ri.[PayerCustomerId] AND bill.[RecipientCustomerId] = ri.[RecipientCustomerId]
            LEFT JOIN [RateModifier] AS rm1 ON bl.[RateModifier1Id] = rm1.[RateModifierId]
            LEFT JOIN [RateModifier] AS rm2 ON bl.[RateModifier2Id] = rm1.[RateModifierId]
            LEFT JOIN [RateModifier] AS rm3 ON bl.[RateModifier3Id] = rm1.[RateModifierId]
            LEFT JOIN [RateModifier] AS rm4 ON bl.[RateModifier4Id] = rm1.[RateModifierId]
   WHERE    BatchAltId = @BatchAltId 
ORDER BY    [FundingSource], b.[StartDate], b.[Description], [CustomerName], [BillingCode], [FromDate], [ToDate]
```

Comment: The only way I can see it happening is if the .rdl is using a datasource that references a different database than when the query is run in SSMS. Have you tried removing the datasource and readding it?

Comment: Can you give an example of a parameter value that returns the correct results, and a parameter value that doesn't? Also can you try to capture RPC and SP:Starting events in addition to the StmtCompleted events you mentioned on twitter? This will make sure you can see the procedure call that SSRS is making (vs. just the statement inside the proc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds silly thing but are you sure the BIDS package is referencing the database on the same server as where SSMS query is running? When I've had things like this happen, I've almost always found an error in the cofiguration of the package and the datasource was pointing to the wrong server.

Comment: This is in our development environment. We have databases for various versions of our software in one instance. The report server had not been updated to have the data source point to the new version database (and neither had BIDS), so reports pointing to older records worked fine, but using a parameter value of a newer record found no rows.